# How to Move a sheet using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, epplus

What is the command needed in **EPPlus**
, to move a worksheet location in a workbook?

I couldn't find any Move command for EPPlus only Interop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are four methods for moving a worksheet. They are

```
excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveAfter()
excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveBefore()
excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveToStart()
excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveToEnd()
```

Answer (score 1):

For anybody finding this in 2021, @chandler is totally correct, but let me add this:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Moves the source worksheet to the start of the worksheets collection
//
// Parameters:
//   sourceName:
//     The name of the source worksheet
public void MoveToStart(string sourceName);

myExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveToStart(myExcelWorkSheetObject.Name);
```

The `worksheetName` input parameter tripped me up.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this job. sharing answer if someone gets help from my answer.

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo("d:\\TestOrder.xlsx");
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

List<string> _sheet = new List<string>();
_sheet.Add("Summary");
_sheet.Add("Vertical");
_sheet.Add("DashBoard");
_sheet.Add("Delta");

int counter = 1;
foreach (var wsname in pck.Workbook.Worksheets)
{
    string worksheetname = wsname.Name;

    int index = _sheet.FindIndex(str => str.Contains(worksheetname));
    pck.Workbook.Worksheets.MoveAfter(counter, index + 1);
    counter++;
}

pck.Save();
```